# Lists items order when items can be on multiple lists (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

So I have a rails app That lets users create lists and put items on that list. As a feature a user can put any one item on multiple lists. Example:

List_1
    -item_1
    -item_2

List_2
    -item_3
    -item_2

The relationship side of it all is complete and working fine.

The next step was to let the user arrange the items in their lists. I installed act_as_list and using jQuery sortable got a simple drag and drop working for sorting items. The issue is each item has one position. So if I change item_2's position to 1 on list_1, item_2's position is now 1 in every list.

I'm trying to think of a way to store item positions relative to the list. Anyone have any thoughts?

Edit to Add code

List model

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :assignments, order: 'position'

end
```

Item model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lists, through: :assignments
  acts_as_list scope: :list
end
```

Assignment model

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :list

  validates_uniqueness_of :item_id, :scope => :list_id
end
```

Comment: which model is the one the user is dragging between?

Comment: The user is viewing a list which is a show view for `@list` where `@items = @list.items`. The user can drag the items up and down to sort them in the list. After each drag the position is saved. Currently what I have is the ability to simple save the items current position when I really need to be able to save the position of that item relative to this list it's on without changing its position in every other list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So an answered my own question with a little time an effort. I've provided an example below for anyone who may run into the issue in the future.

Basically @thedeeno's answer would have worked fine if I was able to use scopes. In my case the list will be user created and hence scopes are not an option.

**Solution:**
So my solution was adding a position column to my assignments table (the join table for my has many through)

This way each assignment could now have a list_id and item_id and a position.

Then in my controller I did the following to populate the @items hash

```
@items = @list.items.order(:position)
```

This gave makes @item has ordered by item positions for their respective list position.

Now the last step was updating their position using sortable. To update the correct item's postion I needed sortable to send the list_id along with each order of the id's. To get the list_id sent with the post I adding a hidden li with and id of the @list like so

```
<li id='list_<%=@list.id %> style='display:none'></li>
```

which meant that my params now looked like this

```
{"list"=>["31"], "item"=>["30", "58", "59", "24", "80", "81"]}
```

Finally using the skills I had learned from http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists I changed my sort action to the following

```
def sort
  @items = params[:item]

  @items.each_with_index do |id, index|
    assignment = Assignment.where(list_id: params[:list], item_id: id).update_all(['position=?', index+1])
  end

render :nothing => true
end
```

That's it! users can now create any number of lists and item to multiple lists and sort each list independently. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can promote these 'lists' to a formal model and then scope acts_as_list position to that model. Similar to the example from the docs:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :order => "position"
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  acts_as_list :scope => :list
end
```

The point of scoping is to make the position relative to another model. You can also have multiple positions scoped to multiple models.

**EDIT:**

If multiple scopes is your issue, you might want to checkout the [sortable](https://github.com/shuber/sortable) gem.

Comment: Adding this did make each list sort it's items by the item position. So thank you. I was doing it manually in the controller before.    However it does not solve the issue of an item having a different position for each list it's on.

Comment: shouldn't it have a different relative position?

Comment: Check out the gem I added to the answer